# How to organise common code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Just getting started with backbone.js, and one of the things I've noticed is that many of my models, collections and views share some very similar methods. I'd like to refactor them & call them from an extracted location (/lib?). I went searching for documentation and/or examples, and was surprised by how little I found (specifically, none). So, a few questions:

- Is there a reason I'm overlooking as to why there are so few examples of backbone methods factored out into common libraries?
- Is there a standard/agreed upon location in backbone projects for shared code?
- Any backbone classes and/or common plugins to help store common methods?

Any ideas appreciated - thanks in advance.

**(EDIT) Example added:**

Take this code from a view. (Admittedly it's too short be actually worth refactoring, but its simplicity makes it a concise example)

```
  destroy: () ->
    @model.destroy()
    @remove()
    return false
```

Suppose I wanted to refactor it into:

```
  destroy: () ->
    restful_destroy_method(this)
```

which then called:

```
 restful_destroy_method: (view) ->
    view.model.destroy()
    view.remove()
    return false
```

from a common library. Any reason why nobody else seems to do this?

Comment: It might help to add a specific example of what kind of common code you're dealing with. There are probably several different ways to solve this, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: *nods* No worries rob. Example added above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the situation, and what your common code is.

In the case of your example, what I might do would be to create a more specific View to extend from.

*<sup>Apologies for the straight JavaScript, I'm not as fluent in CoffeeScript to use it in an answer.</sup>*

```
DestroyableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    destroy: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then, instead of creating `new Backbone.View()`s, I'd create `new DestroyableView()`s. `DestroyableView` could have other common functions, or you could create several different parent definitions and use [`_.extend()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) to apply them all to a single object.

Comment: *nods* Thanks for the answer. My only concern would be that in many instances, I'd quite like to mix-n-match which methods I pull in. One view may want common destroy, send_to_panel, send_email methods, whereas another may want send_to_panel, play_video, etc. I guess I could create a common 'extended_view' that contained all the methods I may want to use in any of the models in my project, but I'm uncertain as to what effect this would have on memory if I were only using a handlful of the extended view's methods in any given view.

Comment: @unclaimedbaggage - Sure, and you could still do that using this. You can [extend](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) from many different sources, each defining its own functions.

Comment: Ahh - I keep forgetting JavaScript is beefier than I think. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Basic View" which own the generic methods :

```
// Create a Basic View which have all generic methods
var BasicView = Backbone.View.extend({
    restful_destroy_method: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
        return false
    }
});

// Create a view which herits the methods of BasicView
var ExampleView = BasicView.extend({
    destroy: function () {
        this.restful_destroy_method();
    }
});
```

You can show an example on jsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/YDMNg/